# How can I fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vlc'' despite installing python-vlc with pip?

Tags: python

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vlc'(still it after installed pip install python-vlc)

I don't know why i have this error although i tried to install it but still that problem. So that can anyone help me to duel with this issue. Thanks a lot
P/s: my python version is 3.11.3 and i use it on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Did you try `pip` or `pip3`? Are you using any virtual environment?

Comment: Yes i try both but still not work and i wasn't using venv also

Comment: What command did you use to install the module and what command did you use to run your script?

Comment: Here sir: pip install python-vlc. After that i have try with pip3 but still that. And for my script, I just run by click button( i use vscode) so that i don't use command for this.

Comment: Run `python3 -m pip list` to check if it's installed. If so then ensure VS Code is using the same `python3` to run your script. You can do this with `which python3` and comparing it to the path VS Code outputs in the terminal.

Comment: After run the first script, i see that vlc has been installed. Then i try the next one and it shows: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3

Comment: I would suggest checking that VS Code is using the same one.